# MongoDB Promise and Result Processing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, promise

I am currently learning about Promises in nodejs, now I am a bit stuck in handling mongoDB query and promise. Here is a sample code that I have below.

```
db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).find( {"$or" :[{"email":req.body.email},{"username":req.body.username}]},function(err,success){
                if (err) {throw new Error("Error in accessing DB - check new user"); }
                return success;
            }).toArray().then(function(value){

                console.log(value.length);
                if (value.length == 0) {
                    db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).insertOne(insert,function(err,success){
                        if (err) {throw new Error("Error in accessing DB - insert new");}
                        return success;
                    }).then(function(value){
                        return resolve("Success")
                    }).catch(function(value){
                        return reject("Error happened during accessing DB, please contact the Admin inside");
                    });
                }
                return reject("Email / Username is not unique");
            }).catch(function(value){
                return reject("Error happened during accessing DB, please contact the Admin");
            });
```

Sorry for a lot of mess in the code. I want to ask couple of things regarding the query handling here. First, how do we properly handle the error in mongodb query, which supposedly handled by this

```
,function(err,success){
            if (err) {throw new Error("Error in accessing DB - check new user"); }
            return success;
        }).
```

piece of code?

Adding the "then" after toArray() solved my previous problem of the promise has not yet resolved when it reached the db insert code. However, now that I have another DB query inside, how do I properly (again) handle the async call? Is the example above correct?

Running this code with no duplication in DB (meaning the first query return null) will result in returning rejection with code "Error happened during accessing DB, please contact the Admin" (the last reject). However, the DB is updated fine, which means that it should reach then instead of catch. The query should have hit the resolve in the middle part and return, but it seems the code trigger the catch somehow.

Comment: I would follow-up your exploring by walking through some articles on how promises work. Here's an example: https://davidwalsh.name/promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question seems to boil down to how promises work. It looks like there are two related-but-different things going on in the code:

1. Using the promises returned from Mongo.
2. Controlling another promise (perhaps returned by this function).

We also seem to be missing a detail - is this within a function that returns another promise? For now let's assume you are and that it looks like this:

```
function addNewUser(req) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Insert the code from the question here.
  });
}
```

Promises can really only be "set" once. They can either be `resolved` or `rejected`. However, subsequent `then()` or `catch()` calls return new Promises. This lets you chain them together to control the flow of the app. Likewise, you can return a new Promise from within the promise handling function to have them work in-order.

So your MongoDB queries could look like this:

```
// First, run the initial query and get a Promise for that
db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).find(...)
   .then(function(existingUsers) {
     // Now that we found what we need, let's insert a new value
     return db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).insertOne(...)
   })
   .then(function(addedUser) {
     // Now we know that we found existing users and insert a new one
     resolve(addedUser); // This resolves the Promise returned from addNewUser()
   });
```

This works to control the order of the MongoDB operations. If you need to have special error handling for for the different cases (like a MongoDB error versus a user-already-exists error say) you can add the conditional checks and calls to `catch()` where needed. For example:

```
// First, run the initial query and get a Promise for that
db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).find(...)
   .then(function(existingUsers) {
     if (existingUsers.length < 1) {
       // Now that we found what we need, let's insert a new value
       return db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).insertOne(...)
     }

     // Throw an error indicating we're in a bad place
     throw new Error('A user with this name already exists!');
   })
   .then(function(addedUser) {
     // Now we know that we found existing users and insert a new one
     resolve(addedUser); // This resolves the Promise returned from addNewUser()
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
     // This will run when an error occurs. It could be a MongoDB error, or perhaps the user-related error thrown earlier.
     reject(err); // This rejects the Promise returned from addNewUser()
   });
```

Comment: Thanks Doug! Now I have understood better about the problem and solved the confusion. Below I have also added some changes which I hope could explain and breakdown the problem for the others.

Comment: This is a detailed walk through. Much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Doug swain before!

Now it seems i understand better about mongodb and promises. The problem with the previous code is that I was trying to overcomplicate callback and promise. the code `function(err,success)` is actually a callback, which should have handled the result. Adding the promise . then was not necessary.

However, as I am trying to promisify all of the node, I changed the code to use promise instead of callback. Here is the final code which is much neater.

```
db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).find(...).toArray().then(function(value2){
if (value2.length > 0){
    return reject("Email / Username is not unique");
}

db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).insertOne(insert).then(function(correct){
    return resolve(correct);
}).catch(function(error){
    throw new Error(error);
});

}).catch(function(err){
console.log(err);
return reject(err);
});
```

The code works just like what I want.
There was also a problem with previous code, as .then can't be used directly after `find(...)`. The `find(...)` query will return a cursor instead of a promise. Therefore, `.toArray()` is needed to use `.then` after.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Mongoose returns a Promise. So if you can use Mongoose and await, it can solve your problems. 1 and 2 are areas which are somewhat tricky.


    let asyncFunction = async()=>{
    let success;
       let data = await db.collection(module.exports.collectionName).find( {"$or" :[{"email":req.body.email},{"username":req.body.username}]};
    })

//1
    new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     if(data.err){error code here}
     else{ resolve (data.toArray());
    }).then((val)=>{
      //val here is data.toArray() value 
      //2 here a callback can be used as insertOne will take time
      if(value.length == 0){
        db.insertOne((insert,(err, success)=>{
                            if (err) {throw new Error("Error in accessing DB - insert new");}
                            success = success;
    }

    })).then(()=>{//use success here..send response or return result})
```

use catch and finally as per your needs at the end